# integrating forms authentication in to mvc4 site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am currently working with an MVC4 and have a secure area to the site. To manage this, I am working with windows authentication. I have implemented this in web forms some time back but this is the first time I have worked with it in respect of MVC.

I am using cookies to store the auth. So when a user authenticates, it gets persisted to cookie. A user could be in a number of different roles. Should this also get persisted to a cookie?

After authentication, how can I check in controllers, filters etc if the user is logged in and if they are a member of a certain role? Does such information need to be loaded in to the users context on each request?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Membership Provider then you should be able to do what you want using Action Filter attributes on your controller methods.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomeControllerAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

or to test for a particular role:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,Moderator")]
public ActionResult SomeControllerActionRequiringSpecificRoles()
{
    return View();
}
```